# autocomplete files on fish shell custom function

Tags: fish

I'm migrating from ZSH to Fish, and the only thing I haven't been able to figure out yet is my `c` function:

**functions/c**:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$PROJECTS/$1"
```

**functions/_c**:

```
#compdef c
_files -W $PROJECTS -/
```

That works nicely on ZSH, I can type `c <tab>` and it completes as if I was doing `cd $PROJECTS` directly.

On fish, I created a `c.fish` like this:

```
function c
    cd $PROJECTS/$argv
end

complete --command c --no-files --arguments='(find $PROJECTS -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2)'
```

But as you can imagine, it doesn't work as the ZSH version, as completions don't know about `$argv`, and won't complete past the first folder.

Is there a way to do the same thing in Fish?

I considered creating an `abbr`, but I really like the way I have it on ZSH today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `c` should act like `cd` with `$PWD` set to `$PROJECTS`, here's one approach:

```
function c_complete
    # get the argument to 'c'
    set arg (commandline -ct)

    # save our PWD
    set saved_pwd $PWD

    # cd to $PROJECTS (and then back after)
    # while in $PROJECTS, complete as if we are 'cd'
    builtin cd $PROJECTS
    and complete -C"cd $arg"
    builtin cd $saved_pwd
end

complete --command c --arguments '(c_complete)'
```